# Relationship one-to-many

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm trying to create a Power Pivot model from some Excel tables but have a problem with the relations between the tables. My model at the moment:

[image: Model]

This picture represents the problem:

[image: problem]

The EX_FieldName is not correctly linked to FieldName because what I want is

> InvolvedParty(cat) -> martialStatus(FieldName) -> martialStatus(Ex_FieldName- -> 1(Count)

If I select the count of the `ExfieldNames` I get that result but not every value is linked to an `Ex_FieldName` and I need all of the `FieldNames` so I need the `countOfModel`.

Is it possible to create this?

Comment: Sorry, I followed you right up to the "If I select the count of the Exfieldnames" part, can you expand a little bit about what you're trying to accomplish and why it's not working? It's not entirely clear.